# Find prime numbers two prime numbers given a certain constraint

Tags: cryptography

The question is:
Find primenumbers p and q if n=pq=39247771 and φ(n) = 39233944.

Does anyone have an idea of how to approach this problem in mathematica?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `FactorInteger[39247771]` is sufficient.

Comment: @yarchik ... and `FactorInteger` evaluates in couple seconds still for a product of two 25-digit primes, but becomes somewhat tedious above that.

Comment: @kirma yes, therefore see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is the product of two distinct primes, $p$ and $q$, then $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq -p -q +1 = n -p -q +1$ which is enough information to find the factorization.  I.e., you know $pq=n$ and $p+q = n+1-\varphi(n)$.

You can therefore use:

```
n = 39247771;
phi= 39233944;
Solve[p q == n && p + q == n + 1 - phi, {p, q}]
(*{{p -> 3989, q -> 9839}, {p -> 9839, q -> 3989}}*)
```

Comment: +1 If you also include that `p` and `q` are ordered (e.g., `p > q`), you won't get the redundant solution.

Comment: Just mentioning a math trick that has been useful to me for those reading, if the sum S and product P of two numbers are known, then they are the roots of the polynomial equation: X^2-SX+P=0 via the root-coefficient relationship of polynomials.

Comment: @userrandrand This trick is known as Vieta's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: oh that's the name ! I wondered what the name was when I was writing that comment. I actually ended up checking that the fastest way to find p and q in the question was either applying Vieta's formula and using the general formula for the roots of degree 2 polynomials or  using Reduce with the second degree polynomial. I am not sure why Solve with the product and sum system was slower.